# Problem with changing sprite color using color code

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework

How can I use color code to change sprite color without using tint. Otherwise it have any plugin to change color of sprite using color code.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Comment: if i assign some colorcode like 0xff00ff,0xff0000 or 0xffff00 etc., the effect must appear on sprite which i want to change color. For example ,sprite.tint=0xffffff; but here i use tint but i don't want to use tint.

Comment: "I don't want to use tint" - why? In Phaser, that's how you typically change a sprite color.

Comment: you are right.But when i use tint it add only certain color and it doesn't give exact color which i want.I want to adjust hue,saturation and RGB colors for my sprite.Is it possible with Phaser? - how?